# CommunicationException in EJB project while running the client class : Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have created a helloworld app in EJB 3.0 with Jboss 5. When i try to run my client class EjbClientApplication, it throws an exception.

Frequently I am getting below exception. I have done a lot of rnd about it but I couldn't found it as I am new to EJB please help.

**Exception:**

> javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to
>   any of  these urls: localhost:1099 and discovery failed with error: 
>   javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception
>   is  java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root
>   exception is  javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect
>   to server  localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is 
>   javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server 
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect]]] at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1763) at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:693) at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:686) at
>   javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392) at
>   com.hex.client.EjbClientApplication.main(EjbClientApplication.java:28)
>   Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Failed to connect to
>   server  localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is 
>   javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to connect to server 
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException:
>   Connection refused: connect]] at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:335) at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.checkRef(NamingContext.java:1734) ...
>   4 more Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Failed to
>   connect to  server localhost/127.0.0.1:1099 [Root exception is 
>   java.net.ConnectException:  Connection refused: connect] at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:305) ...
>   5 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351) at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213) at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200) at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529) at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket
>   (TimedSocketFactory.java:97) at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.TimedSocketFactory.createSocket
>   (TimedSocketFactory.java:82) at
>   org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.getServer(NamingContext.java:301) ...
>   5 more

Jboss server is up with port 127.0.0.1:10001 but I trying to hit this url 127.0.0.1:1099 is this ryt?

**Server Properties:**

- Address:127.0.0.1
- port:8080
- JNDI port:1099

**MyCode: These code comprises in a single EJB project**

**RemoteInterfaceClass:**

```
package com.hex.statelessbean;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote

public interface StatelessSessionBeanRemote {

    public String displayMessage();
 }
```

**StatelessBean:**

```
/**
 * Session Bean implementation class StatelessSessionBean
 */

 package com.hex.statelessbean;

 import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless

public class StatelessSessionBean implements StatelessSessionBeanRemote {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public StatelessSessionBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public String displayMessage() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return "Hello world";
}
```

}

**Client:**

```
package com.hex.client;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.hex.statelessbean.StatelessSessionBeanRemote;

public class EjbClientApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
    "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
    "org.jboss.naming");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost:1099");

    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    StatelessSessionBeanRemote bean = (StatelessSessionBeanRemote) ctx
    .lookup("StatelessSessionBean/remote");
    System.out.println("Message from Bean :" + bean.displayMessage());
    } catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `localhost:1099 to jnp://localhost:1099` and `org.jboss.naming to org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces` and check the name of the ejb. With the annotation `@RemoteBinding` can you give a name for the ejb. Do you have a port offset?

Comment: I have done the changes but even though i am getting same exception.

Comment: @JayanthiM What is your JNDI port in your server configuration? Have you seen your EJB in the server log or JMX Console?Could you try to change the java.naming.factory.url.pkgs value to org.jboss.naming.client?

Comment: In server configuration JNDI port is 1099, Port is 8080, and i have changed value to org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces but frequently i am getting this exception.                                                                                                         javax.naming.CommunicationException: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:1099 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out]

Comment: Hi can i know what is the default JNDI port for jboss 5

Comment: By default: 1099. Under this url: http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/ can you check the port and the EJBs.

Comment: Hi  awagenhoffer, thanks for ur immediate reponse nd help. In Jboss As5 server, **bindings-jboss-beans xml** file in conf folder of deploy, I changed the port of **Naming Service** as default **1099** thn it worked fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Corrected Code:

    **Interface class:**


    package com.hex.statelessbean;

    import javax.ejb.Remote;

    @Remote
    public interface StatelessSessionBeanRemote {

        public String displayMessage();
    }


    **Stateless Bean class:**

    package com.hex.statelessbean;

    import javax.ejb.Stateless;

    /**
     * Session Bean implementation class StatelessSessionBean
     */
    @Stateless
    public class StatelessSessionBean implements StatelessSessionBeanRemote {

        /**
         * Default constructor. 
         */
        public StatelessSessionBean() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            System.out.println("************* Calling from Default constructor ******************");
        }

        @Override
        public String displayMessage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("************* Calling from displayMessage() ******************");
            return "Hello world";
        }

    }


**Client class:**


package com.hex.client;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.hex.statelessbean.StatelessSessionBeanRemote;

public class EjbClientApplication {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws NamingException
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                    "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            properties.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                    "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            properties.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url",
                    "jnp://localhost:1099");
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(properties);
        StatelessSessionBeanRemote bean = (StatelessSessionBeanRemote) ctx
        .lookup("StatelessSessionBean/remote");
        System.out.println("Message from Bean :" + bean.displayMessage());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
}


**LookUp:**

Message from Bean :Hello world
```